# Session Handling in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: python, google-app-engine, firefox, google-chrome, tipfy

I have a problem regarding with session handling in Chrome and Firefox. When in authenticate to a website and I closed it and reopen the home page in Firefox it shows my name . But when I do the same thing in chrome it didnt show my name . it shows as guest. The session for this site implemented by tipfy. do I have to configure the session management?

Comment: "When in authenticate to a website and I closed it and reopen the home page in Firefox it shows my name . But when I do the same thing in firefox it didnt show my name." - You mentioned firefox twice. One has to be chrome, right? Kindly clarify.

Comment: Also, what does this have to do with GAE? I'm guessing you meant to say that when you authenticate in FF and then launch Chrome, it doesn't know you are still you. If that's the case, this is normal way in how browsers work - sessions from one browser do not magically appear in another. Please clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the Tipfy session configuration attributes, Check the path attribute '/' you need to do some modification their